# dajngo-admin-sortable2 doesn't sort order of SortableAdminMixin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I created an app with django and python3 containing several tutorials, which in turn contain multiple content entrys that are saved in another table. Each tutorial is represented by an entry in the exercises tutorial model. I want to be able to sort the tutorials and the contents in the django admin panel. It works fine for the inline tutorial contents with SortableInlineAdminMixin class. It also works fine if I create new tutorials from scratch without having any objects saved before (it works local on my pc if I clone this project and set it up from scratch)

My problem now is, that I have the app setup like you see in the code and pictures below on a ubuntu server with apache, but I can't sort the tutorials (the inline contents still work fine). If i drag and drop them to a new position and reload, they don't save at their new position and fall back to their old position.

**Tutorial and TutorialContent model:**

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


# Page for tutorials
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False, unique=True)

    # Timestamp
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


# Content for tutorials
class TutorialContent(models.Model):
    lesson_page = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, related_name='tutorial_content', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    # Timestamp
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        description = 'Order - ' + str(self.order)
        return description
```

**Tutorial and TutorialContent admin:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Tutorial, TutorialContent
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableInlineAdminMixin, SortableAdminMixin


class TutorialContentInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = TutorialContent


class TutorialAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Tutorial
    inlines = [TutorialContentInline]
    list_display = ['title']


admin.site.register(Tutorial, TutorialAdmin)
```

**Django admin tutorial model panel:**

[image: Django admin tutorial model panel]

**SQLite3 view of the corresponding table:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a little to late, but:

If there is already some model instance persisted in your db when you add the adminsortable2 field in your model, the ordering will not works, you need to build the order a first time with:

```
python manage.py reorder your_app.YourModel
```

Source: https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#initial-data

Hoping this can help.